# rollapply mean with fill as smaller window when doesn't fit

Tags: r, rollapply

Here's sample df:

```
tt <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10)
z <- zoo(seq_along(tt), tt)
## - fill it out to a daily series, zm, using NAs
## using a zero width zoo series g on a grid
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day"))
zm <- merge(z, g)
```

Now if you do:

```
rollapply(zm, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = 'right')
```

This gives you 4 NAs at the beginning. What I want to do is instead when the window is smaller than 5 use a smaller window. So when the data are:

```
2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-08 2000-01-09 2000-01-10 2000-01-11 
         1          2         NA         NA          3          4          5          6         NA          7
```

Then the result would be:

```
2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-08 2000-01-09 2000-01-10 2000-01-11 
1             1.5         1.5        1.5         2         3           4          4.5        4.5       5.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

```
rollapply(zm, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = 'right', partial = TRUE)
```

#### Result

```
> rollapply(zm, 5, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA, align = 'right', partial = TRUE)
2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05 2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-08 2000-01-09 2000-01-10 2000-01-11 
       1.0        1.5        1.5        1.5        2.0        3.0        4.0        4.5        4.5        5.5
```

#### Explanation

From `help("rollapply")`, in the documentation of the `partial` argument:

> partial
>
> logical or numeric. If FALSE (default) then FUN is only applied when
>   all indexes of the rolling window are within the observed time range.
>   If TRUE, then the subset of indexes that are in range are passed to
>   FUN. A numeric argument to partial can be used to determin the minimal
>   window size for partial computations.